# Jsp-Page only visitable if Login was successful

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp

I have a question about Login,Authentification and so on.
I have two JSP-Pages, one is Login.jsp and Home.jsp.
What i want is, that Home.jsp is only visitable for the User,who successfully logged in on Login.jsp.
What is the common way to achieve this?For now it is just a theoretical qustion.
(I use .ajax-Request to communicate with Servlets)

Hope someone can help me out with this :)

Comment: Look into web filters.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do that could be using Spring-Security. Firstable to be sure that your jsp cannot be accessed directly by a url like "hostname/yourAppa/home.jsp) place the jsp in the WEB-INF directory. Use Spring MVC, and so Controler, to manage the access to your views (your jsp) and add Spring Security to create a simple secured acces to all your page.

Answer (score 0):

In the submit button of Login.jsp you will call the servlet and check for the login. If the login is not success redirect back to login.jsp itself.

```
response.sendRedirect("invalidLogin.jsp"); // invalidLogin.jsp or to ur login.jsp
```

Refer

http://met.guc.edu.eg/OnlineTutorials/JSP%20-%20Servlets/Full%20Login%20Example.aspx#

Answer (score 0):

In the JSP

$.ajax({

```
dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        data: { user: 'user_value', 
                pwd: pwd_value},
        url: '/ejemplo/servletEjemplo',   (Url Servlet)
        success: function(data) {
                if( data.exito ){
                    window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
                } else {
                    alert(data.mensaje);
                }
        }
    });
```

In the SERVLET

JSONObject respJSON     = new JSONObject();

respJSON.put("exito", true);

respJSON.put("mensaje", mensaje);

response.getWriter().print(respJSON);

return;